# Symmetric PCh and NCh MOSFETs for variable resistors

Tags: mosfet, analog, current-source, low-voltage, variable

I'm wanting to build a variable voltage-controlled resistor. The resistor would be in series with a 200 uA AC current source and need to be controllable between 1-20 ohm.  My current plan is to take advantage of the ohmic region of MOSFETs as variable voltage-controlled resistors. [image: Here]  is a quick schematic of the circuit (ignore the transistor part numbers).  The voltage sources V2 and V3 (V3 = -V2) would be controlling the 'resistor'.  While one MOSFET is in reverse bias it should act like an open circuit and the other should act like a resistor, and vice versa.  I am trying to use MOSFETs with large ohmic regions so that I get good resolution on the 'resistor'.

The issue I am running into is that, since the MOSFETs must work for AC current, they need to be symmetrical in their resistance to Vgs curve... meaning that the PCh MOSFET with a Vgs of -5 has an equivalent resistance to the NCh MOSFET with a Vgs of 5.  I am new to analog electronics and it is difficult for me to find two symmetrical MOSFETs.

Do you have any suggestions for MOSFETS to use or for MOSFET parameters to consider that may help me narrow down my search?  Thanks.

Comment: If the voltage across the MOSFET is small (which it is for you, 4mV maximum) one MOSFET will do. They conduct in both directions symmetrically. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: That has worked in simulation but did not work in my bench testing.  I think it's because there is a reverse bias threshold voltage that doesn't allow the MOSFET to conduct in reverse unless it surpasses the threshold, similar to a diode.   That's my understanding at least.  

I working with an impedance based navigation system which uses a 200uA, 8kHz current signal.  I want to artificially add impedance onto navigation patches in a tank.

Comment: Your simulation does not match reality in some way, and it's probably not the MOSFET model that's causing the issues. Hard to guess what it might be.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.